# Find expectation of conditional normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian-process, multivariate-distribution

I am struggling with some finding expectation value question .

the question is to find $E[Y|X]$ from the result $P(Y|X)$

with given mean and covariance

$$\mu=[\mu_x, \mu_y]^T$$

$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\
b & c
\end{bmatrix}$$

of a random vector $Z=[X, Y]^T$.

I have found $P(Y|X)=P(X,Y)/\mathcal{N}(X|\mu_x,a)$

and I know $(|)=∫(|)$, but I am not sure if there is further calculate require from there.

Please answer if you know any!

Thank you

Comment: For a general discussion of how a subvector $x_{a}$ is distributed when another subvector $x_{b}$ is known (and $(x_{a},x_{b})=x$ is known to be multivariate normal distributed), see pages 85-87 in Chris Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (pdf freely available online). As gunes said, no complex integration is required, basically just some matrix algebra.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional expectation [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Conditional_distributions) given in wikipedia, which can be adapted as the following:
$$\mathbb E[Y|X=x]=\mu_y+b\frac{c}{a}(x-\mu_x)$$

This formula is not obtained by integration. The conditional distribution of multivariate normal RVs have a well-known form as discussed in the wiki link, which reveals both the mean vector and the covariance matrix. You can also find it by playing around with $P(X,Y)/P(X)$ and making it look like a normal PDF in terms of $Y$.